# Got numberformatexception For input string: "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" for wso2

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have one API that have been published in WSO2 API gateway.
When I test API, I got this error message from console.

> Exception in thread "pool-65-thread-1"
>   **java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"**
>           at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>           at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
>           at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.ipToLong_aroundBody512(APIUtil.java:7851)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.ipToLong(APIUtil.java:7847)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.publisher.DataProcessAndPublishingAgent.run_aroundBody4(DataProcessAndPublishingAgent.java:155)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.throttling.publisher.DataProcessAndPublishingAgent.run(DataProcessAndPublishingAgent.java:141)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

According to the blog, they say it need to disable IPv6.
I just disable by registry for IPv6 and add IPV6support only at JAVA_OPTS at wso2server.bat file.
Then I restart again, it still show as IPv6 address.

> [2020-01-15 14:40:21,171]  INFO - PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager
>   **Pass-through HTTP Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8280**
>
> [2020-01-15 14:40:21,172]  INFO - PassThroughHttpMultiSSLListener Starting
>   Pass-through HTTPS Listener...
>
> [2020-01-15 14:40:21,192]  INFO -
>   PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager **Pass-through HTTPS Listener
>   started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8243**
>
> [2020-01-15 14:40:21,449]  INFO -
>   TaskServiceImpl Task service starting in STANDALONE mode...
>
> [2020-01-15 14:40:21,509]  INFO - RegistryEventingServiceComponent
>   Successfully Initialized Eventing on Registry
>
> [2020-01-15 14:40:21,652]  INFO - JMXServerManager JMX Service URL  :
>   service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi

When I run again, I got same error.
Please help to answer?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest API Manager versions, we have provided IPv6 support for throttling usecases. If you take the latest pack or a WUM updated pack of your current version
, you should not get this issue.

Also as a workaround, you could set an IPv4 address using **X-Forwarded-For** header and invoke the API